# Azure DevOps: Can no longer see Extensions in Project Settings

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Noticed that Azure DevOps is no longer showing the menu options in Project Settings for the Extensions.

Does anyone else see this or know why?

I am unable to update settings for the installed extensions.

Comment: Do you not see it at the org level? Still see it there myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the installed extensions in the Organization settings.

Go organization settings--> Extensions under General. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/how-to/grant-permissions?view=azure-devops) for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same thing, and it only occurred recently.  Yes, the org level extension management is still there, and that only allows for managing which extensions are available to use.

The configuration for the extension usage within each project was a separate section in the project settings - this is missing entirely.  We have need to modify one of our extension configs and can no longer access it to do so.

I believe this must be an Error of type PEBKAC coming from a recent MS update to DevOps.